# Does water in air occur as liquid or as gas?

Tags: solutions

I've learned that in a gas, the solute has to be a gas a well. Is that always the case? How about water in air, is that liquid in a gas, or a gas in a gas?

Comment: Being a gas or a liquid is a property of solution as a whole, and not of individual components.

Comment: @IvanNeretin mm yes but we might consider the solution inside the air, for instance, some times we have aerosols each particle might be considered as a solution itself containing different compounds. I think that the question might be good if the user expands it a little bit.

Comment: Air with aerosols is not a solution.

Comment: Smoke is (mostly) a suspension of solid particles in a gas.

Answer (score 3):

If there's water in your air, it's either in the form of water *vapor* (which is a gas), or water *droplets* (which are a liquid *suspended* in a gas).

Liquid water in air isn't a solution, it's a suspension.

Comment: or rather an aerosol, with droplets disperged in air. Dispersion of liquid in liquids is suspension. Dispersion of liquid in air is aerosol.

Comment: @Poutnik I think I'd rather stick with the more general term. All aerosols are suspensions, but not all suspensions are aerosols -- rain droplets in an updraft are too large to be considered an aerosol, but they're definitely _suspended_ (just not _stably_), right?

Comment: Rather, all aerosols and suspensions are dispersions.